# UI Router how to get target state params with $transitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is for UI Router 1.x

Since `$stateParams` has been deprecated, and there is no longer a global state object you can inject (`$transition$` is not injectable into services/controllers...etc). Similarly it looks like the `$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart')` type events are removed.

This leaves the new `$transitions` object. You can subscribe to events via `onStart`. Problem is the argument is passes to your callback function doesn't always have the state parameters.

Where can I get the state parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I am also missing documentation for the new UI-Router. But this here seems to work:

```
$transitions.onStart ({}, 
    function(trans){ 
        var toState = trans.targetState();
        console.log( toState.params() )
    }
)
```

of course you will have to inject `$transitions` into your module.